# Avoid repeated use of string literal without assigning a new variable

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to learn Haskell by cleaning up some code against the GHCi options`-fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns -Werror`.

The code I'm attempting to clean is:

```
infoM, warningM :: MonadIO m => String -> m ()
[infoM, warningM] = map ($ "Events.Reading") [L.infoM, L.warningM]
```

This is causing a pattern matching error since the match is non-exhaustive.

An easy fix would be:

```
infoM, warningM :: MonadIO m => String -> m ()
infoM = L.infoM "Event.Reading"
warningM = L.warningM "Event.Reading"
```

However, the double use of `"Event.Reading"` seems messy, is there an easy way around this using a combination of either `let`/`in` or `where`?

Comment: Define a constant `stringEventReading :: String` and don't export it?

Comment: The whole file is exported, not sure if this matters.

Comment: I'm not sure if that exported symbol matters anyway. I see no harm in exposing something as harmless as `stringEventReading`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz A good module doesn't clutter the namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with a combinator

```
both :: (Arrow a) => a b c -> a (b, b) (c, c)
both f = f *** f
```

and then write it as

```
infoM, warningM :: MonadIO m => String -> m ()
(infoM, warningM) = both ($ "Events.Reading") (L.infoM, L.warningM)
```

Unfortunately, `both` is not in `Control.Arrow` last time I checked, but I think it should be added. For now, you can just write your own version.

Comment: If you feel like pointless^H^H^H^Hfree golf, `both = join (***)` thanks to the (anonymous) reader monad.  (Alternatively, using [`Data.Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:bimap), it's `join bimap`; it moved to `base` in 7.10.)